# Batch to copy folders with same ending to another existing folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, directory

I want to copy multiple folders with the same ending from a main folder to another folder. My .bat file doesn't work unfortunately. This batch file will be put in the same directory as the main folder.

*Folder structure:*

Folderdirectory/**main folder**/folderxxx**10.1**, folderyyy**10.2**, folderzzz**10.3**, etc.

Location of the batch file:
Folderdirectory/**copy.bat**

*Where to copy the folders:*

Folderdirectory/**1** AAA

1 AAA is the destination folder (The space is on purpose). Other destination folders have the same structure: 2 BBB , 3 CCC, etc.

For example: All folders in Folderdirectory/**main folder**/ with the ending "10.**1**" should be copied to an existing folder Folderdirectory/**1** AAA.
This should be looped in order to copy folders with the ending 10.**2** (copy to Folderdirectory/**2** BBB ), 10.**3** (copy to Folderdirectory/**3** CCC ) , ..., 10.30

The code I wrote:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,30) DO (
  xcopy "%~dp0%\main folder\*10.%%i" "%~dp0\%%i *" /E
)
PAUSE
```

Error I get: (example for i=30)
File not found - 30 *
0 File(s) copied

Thank you in advance! I am new to coding and would be very grateful for any help.
Kind regards,
TamTam

**UPDATE:** I updated the code:
    for /L %%i in (1,1,30) do for /D %%j in ("%~dp0\main folder*10.%%i") do
       xcopy /E /I "%%~j" "%~dp0\%%i*")
    PAUSE

The batch file now copies all folderxxx10.**1**, folderyyy10.**2**, etc. to Folderdirectory/ and not to Folderdirectory/**1** AAA, Folderdirectory/**2** BBB for instance. So, there must be something wrong with the destination "%~dp0\%%i*". 
Furthermore, it copies the files in the folder, not the folder itself.

Thanks so far for your help!

Comment: start by changing `"%~dp0%\ ` to `"%~dp0` the changing `"%~dp0\ ` to `"%~dp0`

Comment: I changed it according to your suggestions. The copying itself works now. Thanks!
But it copies every folder from Folderdirectory/main folder/ to Folderdirectory/
Any suggestions for that?

Comment: edit/update your actual question with the new code and your new request.

Comment: I guess the wildcard in the source of `xcopy` matches files rather than directories, hence you need to nest a `for /D` loop into the `for /L` loop, I think: `for /L %%i in (1,1,30) do for /D %%j in ("%~dp0main folder\*10.%%i") do xcopy /E /I "%%~j" "%~dp0%%i *"`... By the way: do not name a bath file the same as an internal command, `copy`...

Comment: I updated/edited my questions. Thanks for your help.